# Reading from variables that are located in a private method

Tags: java, variables, println

I am having a small problem I am trying to print the contents of a couple of variables which are located in a a private method. but I simply keep getting 'Can Not Find Symbol'

Below is the code that I am trying to read the data from (including the println) also I am very new to java.

```
private void createBooking()
{
     String title;
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     String bookingNo;
     String roomType;

    System.out.print("Enter title: ");
    title = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    firstName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    lastName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter booking number: ");
    bookingNo = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Enter room type: ");
    roomType = keyboard.next();


    aBooking = new Booking (title, firstName, lastName, bookingNo, roomType);

}

public void printCustomerName()
{
    System.out.println (createBooking.title);
}
```

Comment: These methods, are they located in the `Booking` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to put these variables as [*member variables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), and then simply access it without using the `.`-operator.

```
class BookingClass {

    // You also seem to need the following:
    Booking aBooking;

    String title;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String bookingNo;
    String roomType;

    private void createBooking() {

        System.out.print("Enter title: ");
        title = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
        firstName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
        lastName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter booking number: ");
        bookingNo = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Enter room type: ");
        roomType = keyboard.next();

        aBooking = new Booking(title, firstName, lastName, bookingNo, roomType);
    }

    public void printCustomerName() {
        System.out.println(title);
        // ...should perhaps be
        // System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

Since you do create a `Booking` instance however, you may want to get rid of `title`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `bookingNo` and `roomType` and put them in the `Booking` class instead. And then access them through `aBooking.getTitle()` and so on...

Comment: But you still have the problem in the printCustomerName variable.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `aBooking = new Booking(...)` you're creating a new `Booking` object with all those attributes and storing it in the `aBooking` field (I'm guessing it's a field since it's not declared anywhere). This means you have a aBooking field that holds all those attributes (assuming the `Booking` constructor saves the parameters). So, to access those fields you go through the `aBooking` field. Probably something like this:

```
System.out.println(aBooking.getTitle());
```

or, if you're not using getters (you should!):

```
System.out.println(aBooking.title);
```

The variables you declare inside the `createBooking` method stop "existing" once you leave the method. They're not accessible in any way (well, almost).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to variable of a method and cannot use a method as a class instance using a dot operator.

createBooking.something is illegal , you can use that method:  createBooking()

Comment: Yes I realise that the 'System.out.println (createBooking.title);' is wrong, but I dont know how to read whats in the createBooking method

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand totally what you wanna do. But i think you want something like this:

```
public String printCustomerName() {
  // This creates the booking object (aBooking)
  createBooking();

  // You can access the firstname lastname like that (I assume that you have a getter method implemented..)
  return aBooking.getFirstName() + " " + aBooking.getLastName();
}
```

But the createBooking() you should move to another place. Maybe into the Constructor and call it there..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider changing the return type of the `createBooking()` method from `'void'` to `'Booking'`, and then the last line would become:

```
private Booking createBooking()
{
    ...
    ...

    return new Booking(title, firstName, lastName, bookingNo, roomType)``
}
```

After that, your `printCustomerName()` might look like something like:

```
public void printCustomerName()
{
    Booking booking  = createBooking();
    System.out.println (booking.title); // if title is visible, which it probably shouldn't be
    //or
    System.out.println (booking.getTitle()); // if such a method exists...
}
```